# MVC6 controllers for related entities

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I want to provide access to a legacy database to customers via a REST API using ASP.NET 5 / MVC6.
There seem to be many examples for writing controllers for single entities but what I don't find is some guideline on how to write controllers for related entities.
In my domain model there are f.e. two entity classes:

- Device
- MeasuringPoint

and each device can have 1..N measuring points.
I want my controllers to have only Get actions, that is, the API is read-only.
For the Device entity I would use

```
public class DevicesController : Controller
{
    // GET: api/devices
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Device> Get()
    {
        //retrieve all devices
    }
    ...
}
```

The next step would usually be for a user to query all measuring points for a specific (selected) device.

How would I write that controller action?
What is the recommended routing and how would I set that up?

For the client side I found suggestions like:

get api/devices/{ID}/measuringPoints

but I have no idea how this is implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use attribute routing to achieve what you want.

If you have enabled MVC in your Startup class using `app.UseMvc()`, then you already have support for routing via the `RouteAttribute`.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DevicesController : Controller {
    // GET: api/devices
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<Device> Get() {...}
    ...
    // GET: api/devices/5/measuringPoints
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}/measuringPoints")]
    public IEnumerable<MeasuringPoint> GetMeasuringPoint(int id) {...}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that this route would be handled by the devices controller and not the measuring points controller. Just one short question: in the meantime I found that I could also do it in the measuring points controller via a query parameter: /api/measuringPoints?deviceID=17. Comparing these two, would you have any preference, f.e. regarding "RESTful principles" or is this just a matter of taste?

Comment: Matter of taste. The framework allows for the flexibility to do what you prefer. But then when there are all the different principles to follow, sometimes it just boils down to make a choice that won't come back to bite you in the behind. Happy coding. :)

Comment: Seeing that `Device` is the root of the relationship, that is what it lives in the `DevicesController`. You can still have your `MeasuringPointsController` doing the same thing `/api/measuringPoints/{id}/Device/{deviceId}` but you should aim to keep you code DRY

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks